# Global Variables From Userform Problems

Tags: excel, vba, global-variables, userform

Excel 2013
I have read several questions that ask this same question and none of those answers seem to be working for me.

I have a userform where a combobox is used to select the number of variables (1, 2, or 3) to be used later in the module.  Then an OK button.

I have tried declaring a global variable and making it public in the first line of the module and it seems to work when when click through the macro manually, but when I try to use it as a user would it drops the variable for whatever reason?

Module1

```
Public variable As Integer

Private Sub Button1_Click()
    UserForm1.Show
End Sub
```

I assume the Button1_Click() has nothing to do with anything, but wanted to show it and confirm it wasn't part of the problem

Userform1

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    ComboBox1.AddItem 1
    ComboBox1.AddItem 2
    ComboBox1.AddItem 3
End Sub
```

user selects 1 2 or 3

Userform1 still

```
Private Sub OK_Click()
    If ComboBox1.ListIndex = -1 Then
        MsgBox "Select a number"
    Else
        variable = Me.ComboBox1.Value   
        Range("D1").Value = variable'testing
        Unload Me
    End If

    Range("D2").Value = variable 'testing after "Unload Me"???
End Sub
```

'Module1 again

```
Sub Macro2()
    Range("D3").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = variable
End Sub
```

When I F8 through UserForm_Activate() --> OK_Click() --> Macro2() it remembers my variable and puts it in cell D3.

If I just click the buttons as a user would and then manually kick off Macro2() it thinks my variable is 0 (not an option) and I get 0 in cell D3, rather than the variable that was selected by the user.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Assuming I'm following this correctly, you're wanting the selection the user made to be retained after the userform macro completes.  I don't think there is anyway for Excel VBA to make variables persistent.  The best alternative is to write it to a cell (hidden sheet perhaps) and then look to that value when you need it, such as macro2 in your example.

Comment: Check out [these other options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/word/concepts/miscellaneous/storing-values-when-a-macro-ends) too.

Comment: It sounds like you are following my question, thanks!  I could store it in a hidden sheet, I just don't really want to.  Mainly out of stubbornness, I think there has to be a way to do this?  The other options link mentions document variables which sounds like what I want, but is for Word not Excel.  I searched for document variables for Excel and was unable to find any.  If I can't figure it out ill bite the bullet and store it in a cell somewhere, but if someone has a work around I am curious about it.  Thanks again!